# filter data by column's value

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I want to search only lines where a column start with `03:` (hours), but while using below command, showing all the rows where value contain `03`. Its an example the data is pretty much huge in a file.

```
awk '{print $2 " " $3}' logfile | grep "03:"
```

The data:

```
05 00:03:12 0.05
05 00:28:03 0.05
05 00:33:12 0.09
05 03:03:12 0.09
05 03:08:12 0.05
05 03:13:12 0.05
05 03:18:12 0.05
05 03:23:12 0.027
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is always a space before the hour as in the example data, you can just use `grep`:

```
grep " 03:" file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$3 ~ /^03/ {print $2 " " $3}' logfile
```

should do what you want; the $3 ~ /^03/ checks that the third column from the input file ($3) starts with (^) 03. The rest is the awk pattern matching syntax (~ /pattern/). Note that this also saves the overhead of using grep as well (1 loop rather than 2 in programming terms).

Comment: Should be second column?

Comment: its the 3rd column in the input rather than the output (where its the 2nd) - made it clearer in an edit

Comment: I'm only seeing the input with three columns in the question... Oh well, it's easy enough to change if the OP wants to.

Comment: judging by the awk presented that is the output. it looks like the 05 is column $2 of the input and the datetimes are column 3 (e.g. 03:18:12 0.05)

Comment: The third line, "`05 00:33:12 0.09`" would not have passed the `grep`.

Comment: the change is trivial if i'm wrong

Answer (score -1):

```
#awk '{print $2 " " $3}' logfile | grep "03:" | uniq -u
```

Comment: Try this -u print only unique lines

Comment: this filter out uniq line and is not what OP have asked.